# Using java scanner to check two conditions while taking user input

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I need to user to enter an int between 1 and 301.
I have this simple loop here to check for user input.
I just want a single number from the user, and if the user enters *anything* other than an int between 1 and 301, I want to display the print line and prompt the users to try again until they enter a valid input.

```
        while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.print("Invalid Input. Please enter a valid number between 1 and 301: ");
            sc.next();
        }
        int numToCheck = sc.nextInt();
        // do stuff with numToCheck
```

This checks that the input is an int, but I can't seem to find a way to give the int input a bound. I tried to assign the user input to a variable and then check the conditions input < 1 or input > 301, but I get InputMismatchException if user enters a letter. How should I store the user input? (I want to store it as an int to check the conditions, but can't do that since I don't know what the user will enter).

Perhaps there is a better design to accomplish all this. Those are welcomed too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you only want 1 input or do you mean for 3 separate inputs

Comment: every time you call `sc.nextInt()` it get another value. If you want to check the same value more than once, store it in a variable.

Comment: I just need 1 input from the user which is an integer between 1 and 301. Anything else they enter the program should prompt them to try again and enter a valid number this time.

Comment: edited to reflect current issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not saving the value of the of the input. So your program is waiting on the user to enter a number each time it see `"sc.nextInt()"` Assign the input to a variable, and then check the condition. 
EDIT: okay, I'll go the extra mile for you. See if this works.

***Accounted for the case where the user might enter a character instead of a number.

```
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld{

public static void main(String []args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int input;
    while (true){
        if (sc.hasNextInt()){
             input = sc.nextInt(); // Assign the next integer to a variable
             if (input  <= 301  && input >= 1){ // Check if integer meets condition
                   break; // Condition met, break out of loop
            }
        }else{
              sc.next();
        }
        System.out.println("Invalid Input. Please enter a valid number between 1 and 301: ");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: where would I assign input? I can't do it within the while loop since i'd get an inputmismatchexception if the user enters a letter. After I check the condition, I need the user to give it another try but it still has to be an int and within that range. Could you give a more complete snippet?

Comment: @Chrine just encapsulate everything in an `while (sc.hasNextInt())`. Check the updated solution

Comment: thanks for going the extra mile, but unfortunately the update solution isn't working for me. If the user enters a letter, the program skips the entire while loop. I tried to encapsulate everything in a conditional to check for integer input, but same issue.

Comment: @Chrine That's my fault. Completed ignored the possibility of the user entering anything aside from a number. The new solution should work. Typically when you use scanner, you'd want to use TRY AND CATCH to ensure the user enters a valid input.

Comment: I'll give that a shot.

Comment: @Chrine If you can't figure it out, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23787491/checking-user-input-is-a-number?rq=1

Comment: jvm hangs if the user enters a number greater than 301. try entering 305 when the console prompts you. after it gives you the invalid input, enter 30 5 again and see what happens.

Comment: Yeah I actually tried to use try and catch block earlier. It was pretty simple to make sure the input is an integer, the problem comes afterwards. When I try to check if its within bounds, if its not within bounds, i need the user to enter another value. But with this new value, i need to check again to make sure it's not a string or something. That's where I'm stuck at. Along with your solution and a couple I came up with, they are not very reliable always, which worries me.

Comment: @Chine , I need to work on my testing. The problem wasn't hanging, it was just waiting for a second input before printing the Invalid Input msg. Try now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want only 1 input from the user, try following simple code, which takes input from the user until user enters a valid input.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     int flag = 0,x=0;
     while(flag == 0){
         x = in.nextInt();
         if(x<1 || x>301){
             flag = 0;
             System.out.println("Invalid Input.");
         }
         else{
             flag = 1;
         }
     }
```

And if you want user to input **more than 1** inputs (i.e 3 here), than set a counter that increases with every valid input of the user, as following:

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     int flag = 0,x=0,count = 1;
     while(flag == 0){
         x = in.nextInt();
         if(x<1 || x>301){
             flag = 0;
             System.out.println("Invalid Input.");
         }
         else{
             //executes when input is valid
             if(count == 3){
                 flag = 1;
             }
             count++;

         }
     }
```

**Edit:**

If you also want to check whether the input is `Integer` or not, than you have to add one extra condition in above code. And as you said you want only one input from user rather than `3`, you have to change exit condition. Change code as following:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
 int flag = 0,count = 1,x=0,flag1 = 0;
 String y;
 while(flag == 0){
     y = in.next();
     flag1 = 0;
     try{
         x = Integer.parseInt(y);
     }
     catch(NumberFormatException e){
         flag1 = 1;
         System.out.println("Invalid Input.");
     }
     if((x<1 || x>301)&&flag1 == 0){
         flag = 0;
         System.out.println("Invalid Input.");
     }
     else if(flag1 == 0){
         //executes when input is valid
         if(count == 1){   // put count == 3 if you want 3 inputs from user.
             flag = 1;
         }
         count++;
     }
 }
```

Here we are taking the input as a `String` and than converting the `String` into the `Integer` by using `Integer.parseInt()`. If the `String` is not `Integer`, than it will throw the exception and we will continue the loop till the valid input is entered by the user.

Comment: Why are you using an `int` for `flag`?

Comment: code above fails immediately if user enters a letter instead of a number.

Comment: @Chrine check my answer now. I've edited it. It will surely work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran this code, to see if it would show a better performance than yours.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

boolean valid = true;
do {
    if (!valid) {
        System.out.print("Invalid Input. ");
    }
    System.out.print("Please enter a valid number between 1 and 301: ");
    String input = sc.next();
    try {
        int value = Integer.parseInt(input);
        valid = (value >= 1 && value <= 301);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfex) {
        valid = false;
    }
} while (!valid);
```

When the conversion to integer fails, the JVM hangs a little. I believe your problem has more to do with the try / catch mecanism that Scanner performs under the hood, than with design.

Answer (score -1):

Use DO WHILE for result

```
  do{
     System.out.print("value of x : " + x );
     x++;
     System.out.print("\n");
  }while( x < 20 );
```

OK ?